# Double induction and generalizations

Tags: logic, induction

Let $p = p(n,m)$ be a property that depends on $n,m \in \mathbb{N}$. If we want to show that it is true using ordinary induction, we see that $p$ holds for all $n,m \geq 1$ iff the property
$$Q(n) := \left\{p(n,m) : m \geq 1\right\}$$
holds for all $n \geq 1$, and therefore we can apply ordinary induction on $n$ to show that $p$ is true. My questions are the following ones:

1) Is this approach above as simple as it looks like or am I skipping some logical issues?

2) Consider the case when $p$ depends on an uncountable number of parameters, each parameter being a a natural number. For example, if $p = p(\mathbf{x})$, where $\mathbf{x} \in \mathbb{N}^{\mathbb{R}}$. What can we say in this case?

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "simple". Proving $Q(n)$ may be as hard as proving $p(n,m)$ directly, it all depends on what $p$ is. Just to give you an example, suppose $p(n,m)$ is the property "there exists $k \gt \max(n,m)$ such that $2k$ is **not** the sum of two prime numbers". Proving $Q(n)$ would make you famous.

Comment: By simple I mean if proving Q(n) is the right way to use double induction, not refering to the difficulty of proving p

Comment: So the first question only pretends to answer if showing that Q(n) is true is the right way to prove p(n,m) using the so called double induction, it is a very trivial question but I just wanted to be sure.

Comment: The way you describe works, but it's just one way, not the only one. To use induction you only need an appropriate order with some base cases. You could: prove $p(1,1)$ and  $p(n,m)\implies p(n+1,m)\land$  $p(n, m+1)$, **or** prove $p(n,1)\land p(1,m)$ for all $m,n$ and $p(n,m)\implies p(n+1,m+1)$, etc.